# distributed system: sql server broker implementation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a distributed application consisting of 8 servers, all running .NET windows services. Each service polls the database for work packages that are available.

The polling mechanism is important for other reasons (too boring for right now).

I'm thinking that this polling mechanism would be best implemented in a queue as the .NET services will all be polling the database regularly and when under load I don't want deadlocks.

I'm thinking I would want each .NET service to put a message into an input queue. The database server would pop each message of the input queue one at a time, process it, and put a reply message on another queue.

The issue I am having is that most examples of SQL Server Broker (SSB) are between database services and not initiated from a .NET client. I'm wondering if SQL Server Broker is just the wrong tool for this job. I see that the broker T-SQL DML is available from .NET but the way I think this should work doesn't seem to fit with SSB.

I think that I would need a single SSB service with 2 queues (in and out) and a single activation stored procedure.

This doesn't seem to be the way SSB works, am I missing something ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You have asked a good question, but it might get a better response on either http://dba.stackexchange.com or on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You got the picture pretty much right, but there are some missing puzzle pieces in that picture:

- SSB is primarily a communication technology, designed to deliver messages across the network with exactly-once-in-order semantics (EOIO), in a fully transactional fashion. It handles network connectivity (authentication, traffic confidentiality and integrity) and acknowledgement and retry logic for transmission.
- [Internal Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is an unique technology in that it eliminates the requirement for a resident service to poll the queue. Polling can never achieve the dynamic balance needed for low latency *and* low resource consumption under light load. Polling forces either high latency (infrequent polling to save resources) or high resource utilization (frequent polling required to provide low latency). Internal activation also has self-tunning capability to ramp up more processors to answer to spikes in load (via `max_queue_readers`) while at the same time still being capable of tuning down the processing under low load, by deactivating processors. One of the often overlooked advantages of the Internal Activation mechanism is the fact that is fully contained within a database, ie. it fails over with a cluster or database mirroring failover, and it travels with the database in backups and copy-attach operations. There is also an [External Activation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2009/05/18/get-started-with-using-external-activator.aspx) mechanism, but in general I much more favor the internal one for anything that fits an internal context (Eg. *not* and HTTP request, that must be handled outside the engine process...)
- [Conversation Group Locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  is again unique and is a means to provide exclusive access to correlated message processing. Application can take advantage by using the `conversation_group_id` as a business logic key and this pretty much completely eliminates deadlocks, even under heavy multithreading.

There is also one issue which you got wrong about Service Broker: the need to put a response into a separate queue. Unlike most queueing products with which you may be familiar, SSB primitive is not the message but a 'conversation'. A conversation is a fully duplex, bidirectional communication channel, you can think of it much like a TCP socket. An SSB service does not need to 'put responses in a queue' but instead it can simply send a response on the conversation handle of the received message (much like how you would respond in a TCP socket server by issue a `send` on the *same* socket you got the request from, not by opening a new socket and sending a response). Furthermore SSB will take care of the inherent *message correlation* so that the sender will know exactly the response belong to *which* request it sent, since the response will come back on the same conversation handle the request was sent on (much like in a TCP socket case the client receives the response from the server on the same socket it sent the request on). This conversation handle is important again when it comes to the correlation locking of related conversation groups, see the link above.

You can embed .Net logic into Service Broker processing via SQLCLR. Almost all SSB applciations have a non-SSB service at at least one end, directly or indirectly (eg. via a trigger), a distributed application entirely contained in the database is of little use.